# Okular snap package fails to find libKF5Parts.so.5

Tags: 16.04, snap, okular

recentely i installed Okular in Ubuntu 16.04 via snap using

`sudo snap install okular`

But when I try to open Okular through the icon in the menu nothing happens, so I try in the terminal and I get this message:

```
okular: error while loading shared libraries: libKF5Parts.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I already installed libKF5Parts5 through

```
sudo apt install libkf5parts5
```

But nothing happened, does anyone know a solution? Is this a bug in okular snap package?

Thanks for the attention, and sorry for the not so good English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The library is part of the `kde-frameworks-5` snap which you need to install first. Do this to fix it:-

```
sudo snap remove okular
sudo snap install kde-frameworks-5
sudo snap install okular
```

Comment: Thank you, that solved the problem, however unfortunately this also means that some more megabytes of downloads will be needed. It is acceptable, since the snap is still maturing.